# Enable CKeditor on Webform's textarea

Tags: webforms, wysiwyg

I'm trying to create a contact form supporting HTML formatting with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor). So I created a new webform with a single field of type Textarea and now I have a simple webform with the basic textarea.

How can I enable rich text formatting on this form? It doesn't work by default and I cannot find any option to enable it neither in Webform nor CKeditor settings.

Comment: May I know have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet. I have installed only Webform and CKEditor and I'm looking for a simple module that will bind them together (without extra dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

[Webform HTML Textarea](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_html_textarea)

Try this module.

Comment: Does it support CKeditor natively or I have to install the [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module? I have not found this info in the module description.

Comment: You have to install Wysiwyg module. Once it done, choose html textarea instead of normal textarea. (When you create the field)